# Creating a script in Python 3 to compare two CSVs and output the similarities and differences between the two into another set of CSVs

Tags: python, mysql, csv, compare

I have two CSVs, ideally the CSVs will contain same data, in reality sometimes the content may differ here and there. Instead of manually browsing the two CSVs and find out whats same and different, I am trying to create a python script which I will run weekly that will tell me whats same and what not.

Here's the logic.
1. Given 2 CSVs
2. Compare them row by row.
3. Any rows that are different between the two CSVs should be recorded into an another CSV (the entire row/s)
4. Any rows that are same between the CSVs should be recorded into another CSV (the entire row/s).

This will help me visually see what the differences are and action them accordingly.

Below is an example of what I am looking for.

[image]

The code below is what I have so far

```
with open('Excel 1.csv', 'r') as csvOne, open('Excel 2.csv', 'r') as csvTwo:
    csvOne = csvOne.readlines()
    csvTWO = csvTWO.readlines()

 with open('resultsSame.csv', 'w') as resultFileSame:
     for row in csvTWO:
         if row not in csvONE:
            resultFileSame.write(row)

 with open('resultsDifference.csv', 'w') as resultFileDifference:
     for row in csvTWO:
         if row in csvONE:
             resultFileDifference.write(row)
```

I want the script to compare rows and only if there is a similarity or differences between rows output that into another set of CSVs. The above code works but it removes the columns which are in one CSV and not the other and not rows. I want to keep the columns even though if they are not in the other CSV and only show me what roles are in one or the other in separate CSVs.

Please see below the results I get when I run the first code you've given, on your dataset example.

[image: resultsSame.cSV]
[image: resultsDifference.CSV]

If you look at the above, I can't quite seem to figure out how your getting the output that you are, as that is exactly what I want! To be honest, I don't need to print out the headers as I am comparing those as well, they can sometime end of different due to user error.

[image: Printed df1 and df2]

Answer (score 0):

Using pandas will make your work easier. Here is the snippet and is self explanatory.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv('excel1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('excel2.csv')

merged = df1.merge(df2, indicator=True, how='outer')
diff_df = merged[merged['_merge'] == 'right_only'].drop('_merge', axis=1)
similar_df = merged[merged['_merge'] == 'both'].drop('_merge', axis=1)
print(diff_df)
print(similar_df)

diff_df.to_csv('resultsDifference.csv', index=False)
similar_df.to_csv('resultsSame.csv', index=False)
```

Documentation of pandas merge function [Pandas-merge function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

I've created the script based on the example you've given in your question. Here is the snap of inputs and outputs of the example.

**Excel1**
[image: Excel1]

**Excel2**
[image: Excel2]

**resultsSame.csv**
[image: resultsSame.csv]

**resultsDifference.csv**
[image: resultsDifference.csv]

I'm sure the script produces the results what you've quoted in your question except the index. If you are interested in the row indices as in your question, then below is the updated script. Let me know whether it meets your needs.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv('excel1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('excel2.csv')

merged = df1.merge(df2, indicator=True, how='outer')
diff_df = merged[merged['_merge'] == 'right_only'].drop('_merge', axis=1)
similar_df = merged[merged['_merge'] == 'both'].drop('_merge', axis=1)
diff_df.index = range(1,len(diff_df)+1)
similar_df.index = range(1,len(similar_df)+1)
diff_df.to_csv('resultsDifference.csv')
similar_df.to_csv('resultsSame.csv')
```

Ah! I'm wondering!!! These are the CSV file contents I have..
**excel1.csv**

```
A,B,C,D
A,A,A,A
B,B,B,B
C,C,C,A
D,,,
```

**excel2.csv**

```
A,B,C,D
A,A,A,A
B,B,B,B
C,C,C,C
D,D,,
```

Comment: I assume I need to install pandas module for that, as I get an error. Is there a way to do what I want without the module? Would really appreciate.

Comment: Of course yon can. I've posted an another answer here. I've added piece of code to your code that just writes header. You may get handy functionalities with pandas and you can very well install with just "pip install pandas" (if you have pip or other installation sources/methods)

Comment: Vivek, I am new to Python, and I've install pandas module as well now. The above code does work but I am not sure what it is really outputting - I don't think that is something that I want. All I need is given 2 csvs to output another 2 csvs which show similarities and differences between the two.

Comment: Hi @AdamJohns I've added a snippet that writes index along with similarities/differences into CSVs.

Comment: Could you please add screenshots of input dataframes. I mean, with python print statements. "print(df1); print(df2);". I'm doubting input CSVs.

Comment: Please see the screenshot attached.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159900/discussion-between-vivek-harikrishnan-and-adam-johns).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the modified version of your code.

```
with open('excel1.csv', 'r') as csvOne, open('excel2.csv', 'r') as csvTwo:
  csvONE = csvOne.readlines()
  csvTWO = csvTwo.readlines()

with open('resultsDifference.csv', 'w') as resultFileDifference:
 # Write the header to difference file. 
 # Because, the headers are same for 2 input CSVs, the header row will be obviously into resultsSame.csv
 resultFileDifference.write(csvONE[0])
 for row in csvTWO:
     if row not in csvONE:
        resultFileDifference.write(row)

with open('resultsSame.csv', 'w') as resultFileSame:
 for row in csvTWO:
     if row in csvONE:
         resultFileSame.write(row)
```

Comment: I can't quite figure out what you've done with swapping the resultsSame with resultsDifference?

Comment: Hi @AdamJohns I'm believe you would like to capture/write the difference between two CSVs into resultsDifference.csv and similarities into resultsSame.csv. But somehow the file names have got interchanged, so I just managed to put them appropriate loops and left with not renaming the variables. I've edited my answer now. Important snippet there is to write the header in difference file. That's it!

Comment: Anyhow, you will not get row indices with the answer I've given here. You may get the row indices with pandas version of the code.